# Consulta distinct mas fecha menor en django

Tags: django, django-models, orm

tengo un modelo llamado movimientos el cual tiene una foranea llamada animal y un campo llamado fecha, necesito obtener 1 registro por animal donde la fecha sea la menor, por ejemplo la siguiente imagen, me deberia dejar solamemte los registros resaltados en rojo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intente hacer el filter con las siguiente consulta

```
context['numero'] = Movimiento.objects.distinct('animal')
```

pero al hacer esta consulta me arroja estos resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los cuales no son los que quiero como resultado.

Este es mi modelo movimientos

```
class Movimiento(models.Model):
    ESTADOS = (
        (0, 'Vivo'),
        (1, 'Muerto'),
        (2, 'Aumento'),
        (3, 'Vendido'),
    )
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, verbose_name="Animal", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    finca = models.ForeignKey(Finca, verbose_name="Finca", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    peso = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Peso", null=True, blank=True)
    comentarios = models.CharField(verbose_name="Comentarios", max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    fecha = models.DateField(verbose_name="Fecha", default=datetime.date.today)
    precio  = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Precio", null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    estado = models.IntegerField(choices=ESTADOS, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.animal.numero

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'movimientos'
```

Esta es mi clase index

```
class IndexAnimal(ListView):
    model = Movimiento
    template_name = 'animal/animal_list.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['movs'] = Movimiento.objects.distinct('animal')
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  # Linea de test
        return context
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para esperar el resultado que quieres solo faltaria un detalle, hacerle un cambio a la consulta que hiciste quedando algo como lo siguiente:

```
context['movs'] = Movimiento.objects.distinct('animal').order_by('animal', 'fecha')
```

con eso deberias solucionarse el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono <3